# Blink hidden and using blocks

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, objective-c-blocks

I have the method:

```
- (void)blinkView:(UIView *)view
{
    view.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
    view.hidden = NO;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Blinking" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    view.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

How can i write this code with blocks, and how i must implement method with reverse effect (hide uiview with blink) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIView transitionWithView: view
       duration:0.6f
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
       animations:^{ view.layer.opacity = 1.0f; }
       completion:NULL];
```

or

```
[UIView transitionWithView: view
       duration:0.6f
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
       animations:^{ view.layer.opacity = 1.0f; }
       completion:NULL];
```

You can set the repeat count by recursively calling the animation block (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8999236/1072846)).

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UIView**'s **setAnimationDelegate:** and **setAnimationDidStopSelector:**

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Blinking" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
view.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];


- (void) animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    // add your final code here : you can give new animation effect here.
}
```

Or try **animateWithDuration** (available only in iOS 4 or later)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                 animations:^{
                             view.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
                             }
                 completion:^(BOOL  completed){
// add your final code here : you can give new animation effect here.
                                              }
                                           ];
```