# internal compiler error: Bus error: 10

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, compiler-construction

I have written code for an animation that shakes a UIImageView on the screen, but although the syntax seems to be correct, I am getting an obscure "`internal compiler error: Bus error: 10`" when building. Any idea why?

```
-(IBAction)shakeCircle{
    int d = 3;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05
    animations:^{myCircle.center = CGPointMake(myCircle.center.x+d, myCircle.center.y-d);}
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05
    animations:^{myCircle.center = CGPointMake(myCircle.center.x-d, myCircle.center.y+d);}
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        //but if I comment from here..
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05
        animations:^{myCircle.center = CGPointMake(myCircle.center.x+d, myCircle.center.y-d);}
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05
        animations:^{myCircle.center = CGPointMake(myCircle.center.x-d, myCircle.center.y+d);}
        ];
        }
        ];
        //... to here the code will build.

    }
    ];
    }
    ];
}
```

Note that if I comment out the last five lines of animation code, everything compiles fine.... What *is* going on?

I have tried switching to different compilers, that didn't work. I made sure that there's just one `myCircle` and that the only time it ever gets referred to is when it gets declared, and in that method!

Comment: Is the search function on StackOverflow and/or Google broken? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035640/xcode-bus-error-when-compiling

Comment: Mr Bull, I took a look at similar questions before posting, I think the root of my problem is different.

Comment: Would be helpful if you edited your question and told people what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little workaround that solves the problem through recursive calls to the function.   Assign to `int d` the amount by which to shake, then

```
int d = 3;
-(IBAction)shakeMyCircle{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05
    animations:^{myCircle.center = CGPointMake(myCircle.center.x+3, myCircle.center.y-3);}
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05
        animations:^{myCircle.center = CGPointMake(myCircle.center.x-3, myCircle.center.y+3);}
        completion:^(BOOL finished) 
        {   
            d--;
            if(d>0) [self shakemyCircle];
            if(d == 0) d = 3;
        }
        ];
    }
    ];
}
```